# load data local by drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

before drag  is  and after drag on  there load data local .load( "file_from_local.html"); and how it can be list??

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $( "#div2" ).load( "file_from_local.html");
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: I am a little confused on what you are trying to do but your code does not even work so lets start from there.

You can do this without any jquery. A simple JS will work.

```html
<style>
.div1, .div2 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<div class="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```